# Is React's data-binding really one way? It seems like it is two way

Tags: angularjs, reactjs

This is from a couple React tutorials that I'm currently reading:

> the State drives what the guys at Facebook call one-way reactive data
>   flow, meaning that our UI will react to every change of state.

and

> Typically UI’s have lots of state which makes managing state
>   difficult. By re-rendering the virtual DOM every time any state change
>   occurs, React makes it easier to think about what state your
>   application is in.   The process looks something like this,   Signal
>   to notify our app some data has changed→ Re-render virtual DOM  ->
>   Diff previous virtual DOM with new virtual DOM -> Only update real DOM
>   with necessary changes.

The first quote seems to suggest that the data flow goes from React to the UI. But the second quote seems to suggest that it goes from the DOM to React which then re-renders the virtual DOM and the diff process than repaints the real DOM. This sounds a lot like Angular's two-way data binding.

Is this true? What am I missing? Is one-way reactive data flow just another name for Angular's two-way data binding?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think it's necessary to make a distinction between React and Flux, both of which implement a uni-directional data flow. I'll only touch on React here.

In Angular a change to the DOM will directly mutate the value of bound scope variables in your controller thanks to angular's two-way data binding and the digest loop. It is two way because, of course, any change in your controller is also directly reflected in the view attached to it.

Think of Angular as `Controller <--> View`

In React a component always renders its DOM based on its props and internal state. A React component can listen to event being fired in the DOM it rendered, which might sound a bit like two-way data flow on the face of it but there is an important difference: An event fired on the DOM does not directly update the internal state of the component. The component must listen to the event and then explicitly update the component with the new state. This change of state then triggers the DOM to be re-rendered (if it needs to). In this way the components props and state are the single source of truth and always drive the DOM output. Of course changes in the DOM can affect the component but it is done in an indirect manner.

Think of React as `Component State --> DOM --> New Component State --> New DOM`

Comment: Nice answer! Can I regard the Reactive Dataflow as **desc the data changes over time**? Coz it seems in your example, the `Component State --> DOM --> New Component State --> New DOM` has another dimension: **time**.

Comment: Yes. Time is an important concept here. There are a number of reactive programming libraries such as RxJS that are more explicit with their modelling of time. These also work very nicely with React.

Comment: Cool, I will go and look at them.

Comment: Put another way, with 2-way binding there are 2 representations of state that need to be synced.  With 1-way data flow, the view emits events ("something happened") _without changing_. The view itself is a function of state (that is, the view's "state" is really just a transformation into DOM of the current. It can seem like 2-way, but really, it's more like 2 1-way flows: state always and only flows down to the view, and events always flow from view to whatever's updating state.

Answer (score 5):

Angular's two way of binding's essence is that the view is bound both to the model and the user's input.

[image: Angular's two way of binding]

With React, the view is bound only to the state and a user's input cannot directly change the view, but triggers the component's own methods to update its state and Reacts job is to rerender the view so it reflects the state.

[image: React's one way binding]

Comment: I think the example of React is not the two way binding in React way, actually it's in **FLUX way**. Correct me if I am wrong about this. : )

Comment: If you can try to update your answer, that would help us a lot.

Comment: how is this different than react? or different than what @djskinner wrote?

Answer (score 3):

The flow here is:

### Component

state-> virtual DOM -> DOM

This is always the flow, whether its initial render or second render.

1. The quoted bit is:state->virtual DOM -> DOM
2. newStateDifferentFromOldState -> virtual DOM
3. diff virtual DOM from 1 with virtual DOM from 2
4. Only update the elements of the DOM that are the net difference of performing 3.

e.g. 1->2->3->4, repeat in this order from 2 (2->3->4->2->3->4...so on)

This is in no way related to the concept of two way data binding.